# How to store references to objects from one vector in another vector in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I've got a vector `std::vector<MyClass> myclass_vec(10)` with 10 initialized objects of `MyClass`. Now I would like to loop over this vector and store a reference to every `MyClass` object in another vector `std::vector<MyClass> myclass_vec_refs`. The reason why I would like to store references is so because I don't have to copy the objects and obviously, refer to the same object as in `myclass_vec`.

For some reason, this doesn't work out as aspected. Do I have to declare `std::vector<&MyClass> myclass_vec_refs` like so?

As I was looking through other questions asked here I read about `std::unique_ptr`. If I change `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> myclass_vec(10)` then I wouldn't able to have a reference or pointer in `myclass_vec_refs` since they are declared unique. Correct me please if I'm mistaken.

Another approach was using `std::shared_ptr`. Since it holds a reference counter I would be able to have `myclass_vec_refs` point to objects in `myclass_vec`, but I read this introduces quite some overhead and share_ptr should only be used as a last resort.

I also don't know if referencing like I'm attempting works out. What happens if an object in `myclass_vec` is deleted? Is the `myclass_vec_refs` vector resized by -1 since the object doesn't exist anymore or is it just pointing to bad memory?

Is it possible to `emplace_back` a reference in the `myclass_vec_refs` vector? Since this creates the object in-place I guess this doesn't work and only `push_back` can be used?

Comment: Why not just store an iterator in the other vector?

Comment: why not store pointers instead of the allocated object ?

Comment: Why not store indexes instead?

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant because if the vector gets deleted, the pointers point to garbage.

Comment: @JossieCalderon: yes it's why you need to update the vector to remove the pointer. don't see any problem until there.

Comment: @JossieCalderon Same goes for references, iterator that get invalidated, and indexes.

Comment: What do you actually want to do with `myclass_vec_refs`?

Comment: Can you post the code of what you tried?

Comment: I have this `myclass_vec` defined outside a class and pass if by reference to a class which is generating a lookup table based on objects in `myclass_vec`. So the lookup table should then hold some sort of reference pointer or index to the actual object I would like to look up.

Comment: As @Holt says, what is the *actual problem* you want to solve with this second vector? No matter what you store in the second vector you need to keep the two vectors i sync, which creates more work for you, perhaps there are better solutions to your actual problem? Better designs? Please [read about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @SeanM.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922360/why-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Probably because indexes may change when new elements are **inserted** to or removed from first vector

Comment: Maybe all your problems will go away if you just use a reference or pointer to `myclass_vec` ? If you just don't want to have copies of `myclass_vec` when you pass it around, a reference / pointer to it might be all you need. This will also fix all your subsequent issues / questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** make a vector of references.
Why?

A reference must refer to an actual object at all times, and vectors by design must be able to create "empty" objects (i.e. default constructor) dynamically for you.

You can however create a vector of pointers.

If the other vector is modified in any way, your pointers will become invalid.
If this is a problem to you, use a **map** or **set** instead.

Comment: It is true that you cannot have vectors of references, but your reasoning is wrong. A vector does not require the object to be default constructible. Although, some member functions of vector do (at least `resize( size_type count )` and `vector( size_type count )` are such), but you don't have to use those functions to use vector.

Comment: @user2079303: Actually, `vector` does not require that. Or more to the point, `vector` *alone* doesn't impose a copy/move requirement. It is the methods of `vector` that actually insert/remove items that impose that requirement. The basic thing `vector<T>` requires of `T` is Erasable via the allocator's `destroy` function. And for `std::allocator`, references are not.

Comment: @NicolBolas oh, I made the same mistake that I was correcting in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As answered here: [Strange Template Deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106414/strange-template-deduction/38107076#38107076)

The trick is to use `std::reference_wrapper<>`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename container_ty_, class Comp>
auto where(container_ty_& V, Comp&& comp)
{
    using value_type = typename container_ty_::value_type;
    using reference =
    std::conditional_t<
      std::is_const<container_ty_>::value,
        std::reference_wrapper<const value_type>,
        std::reference_wrapper<value_type>
    >;

    std::vector<reference> cursor;

    for(auto& VAL : V)
        if(comp(VAL))
            cursor.push_back(VAL);

    return cursor;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> tVect = {0, 5, 2, 1, 7, 9};

    //Why must std::vector<int> be passed...
    auto vec = where(tVect, [](const int& V) -> bool { return V > 5; });

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (int& v) { std::cout << v++ << std::endl; });
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::for_each(tVect.begin(), tVect.end(), [](const int& v) { std::cout << v << std::endl; });
}
```

Comment: @Sean M.: This is the real answer of all your questions!